# can't get program to iterate properly (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable)

Tags: python

So just getting started learning python. as practice i decided to build a program that would handle my attacks for my D&D character and i can't quite seem to get this to iterate properly.

```
from random import randint

def roll_dice():
    type = raw_input("Initiative (i) or Attack (a): ") #variable that is passed through the function
    roll = randint(1,20)
    if roll == 1:
        print "Natural 1"
    elif roll == 20:
        print "Natural 20"
    else:
        crit = "n"
    if type == 'i':
        result = roll + 5
        print "Initiative = %d" % result
        return 
    elif type == 'a':
""" most of the rest of the program is after here but that all works fine so there is no reason to take up space with that""" 

roll_dice()
for type in roll_dice():
    if type == 'a' or type == 'i':
        continue
```

program will loop once and then gives me:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I know this means that the second time it goes to iterate it is passing nothing through but i can't quite figure out how to fix it.

any help and/or explanations would be greatly appreciated

Edit: 
I know it does not run as posted. The whole thing is over 100 lines and I did not want to swamp people with that. Once I get home I will post with the whole thing.

For clarification: With the whole program it will run once through loop back to the start and then return the error after a completed second run through the program. So the first time through the loop works it is after the completed second run and attempting to start a third.

Comment: Why do you imagine the result of your function call should be iterable? It **always returns `None`** To clarify, it would be helpful if you explained what you expect this to do and why.

Comment: "I know this means that the second time it goes to iterate it " you only try to iterate once, and it fails immediately. There is no second time you go to iterate.

Comment: Your posted code has three blocking points for me: (1) It fails to run as posted.  (2) Your code requires manual input; please provide an example that shows the error on its own.  (3) The code is not minimal; you've given us the entire program, rather than reducing it to the expected minimal case.

Comment: more explanation on what is the function returning or is the `type` used in the loop supposed to be the function attribute?

Comment: For the record, I think the downvotes are harsh for a first post. This isn't too bad as far as first questions go, it at least includes an error and the code. I'd at least give the OP a chance to respond to comments...

Comment: There are several basics of data and program flow on which you're unclear.  Because of the various problems, as well as your lack of program specification, we can't really help you fix this.  Your immediate error is that your fucntion `return`s nothing, but the main program assumes that it returns a sequence of characters.  Even more confusing, the first line of tha main program appears to (properly) assume that the function returns nothing.

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like your `roll_dice()` function returns anything, causing the TypeError. The reason it "seems" like the program loops once is because of the line right before the for loop, which calls the function.

What it seems like you are trying to do is extract the `type` variable from inside your function, which can be done by returning the type with `return type` instead of just `return` and using the if statement alone. To loop until `type` isn't `a` or `i`, a `while` loop may be more useful, like so:

```
while True:
    type = roll_dice()
    if type != 'a' and type != 'i':
        break
```